# jquery выдает не правильный url. Как пофиксить этот баг?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modx

Хай всем помогите решить проблему с jquery. В общем делал сайт с подгрузкой контента на странице без перезагрузки самого сайта не могу пофиксить баг. Проблем с url
Вот код

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Check for hash value in URL
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav-page li a').each(function(){
var href = $(this).attr('href');
if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
var toLoad = hash+'.html #content-page';
$('#content-page').load(toLoad)
}
});

$('#nav-page li a').click(function(){

var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content-page';
$('#content-page').hide('fast',loadContent);
$('#load-page').remove();
$('#content-page').append('<div class="load-page"><p>LOADING...</p></div>');
$('#load-page').fadeIn('normal');
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length=100);
function loadContent() {
$('#content-page').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
}
function showNewContent() {
$('#content-page').slideDown('normal',hideLoader());
}
function hideLoader() {
$('#load').fadeOut('normal');
}

var title = $('.title-page').text();
var bread = $('.breadcrumb-item-page').text();
$('.breadcrumb-item-page').text(title);
return false;

});
});
```

Грешу на эту строчку

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length=100);
```

Выдает при подгрузке url

```
http://goodbadnewsapp.com/uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/registracziya-tovarnogo-znaka#uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/mezhdunarodnaya-registracsia
```

Как сделать чтобы он указывал верный

Пример
Было

```
http://goodbadnewsapp.com/uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/registracziya-tovarnogo-znaka
```

Стало

```
http://goodbadnewsapp.com/uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/mezhdunarodnaya-registracsia
```

вот по просьбе добавил Html

```
<div class="widget service-list-widget widget service-list-widget-top">
<h3>Товарные знаки</h3>
<ul id="nav-page" сlass="auxiliary-menu">
<li class="first active active-menu-page"><a href="uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/registracziya-tovarnogo-znaka">Регистрация товарного знака</a></li>
<li><a href="uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/proverka-tovarnogo-znaka.pdf">Проверка товарного знака</a></li>
<li><a href="uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/mezhdunarodnaya-registracsia">Международная регистрация</a></li>
<li><a href="uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/podgotovka-vozrazheniya-na-otkaz-registraczii">Подготовка возражения на отказ регистрации</a></li><li><a href="uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/prodlenie-sroka-dejstviya">Продление срока действия</a></li>
<li><a href="uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/vnesenie-izmeneniya-v-tovarniy-znak">Внесение изменения в товарный знак</a></li>
<li><a href="uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/zashhita-tovarnogo-znaka-ot-narusheniya">Защита товарного знака от нарушения</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="uslugi/tovarnyie-znaki/registracziya-obshheizvestnogo-znaka">Регистрация общеизвестного знака</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример html что у вас там в href лежит.

Comment: Пора забыть про `hash` для `url` его используют для перемещения по странице, а не на другие страницы, для перемещения на другие страницы нужно использовать `History API`.